# Workspace support removed in Spyder 3

Tags: python, spyder

When using Spyder2 one can create a workspace, a project and also say that two ore more projects were related. In spyder 3 one can only create projects, the concept of workspace seems to have disappeared. Is this true? The concept of related projects allowed one to import objects from a related project, as if they were objects defined in an installed package.

Is it true that these features have disappeared in Spyder3? It seems to me so, but I still cannot believe it. If so, what were the reasons behind this choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) That's correct, workspaces were removed in Spyder 3 and I think they won't come back, sorry.

We decided to do that because they made the graphical interface confusing and the implementation very hard to maintain and extend. So we decided to rewrite our Projects support from scratch in Spyder 3.